# Difference between Word.CustomXmlPart and Office.CustomXmlParts

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

Word.CustomXmlPart is still in preview and not recommended to use [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.customxmlpart?view=word-js-preview#setXml_xml_) but I can use  Office.CustomXmlParts to store any data [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.customxmlparts?view=word-js-1.3). I don't find any documentation around difference between these two. What basically is difference between these two and what should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

They do essentially the same things. The Word-specific APIs perform much better because they use batching of commands, whereas the Common APIs make a round trip between the add-in and the document with every command. For that reason, we recommend that when the Word-specific APIs are released, you use them. Until then, for production add-ins, use the Common APIs (Office.CustomXmlParts).

Comment: I doubt this as I implemented office.customXmlParts but issue I am facing is -> I added custom xml in document in office on web (working fine on web), downloaded it and that custom parts node is deleted when running on desktop application.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Please report that as an issue on the Office.js repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues